# How to make SBCL optimize away possible call to FDEFINITION?

Tags: optimization, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Apologies: I don't have sufficient knowledge to rework this as an easy to understand code snippet.

I've been using the SBCL compiler notes as signs to what might be improved but I'm well out of my depth with this —

```
; compiling (DEFUN EXECUTE-PARALLEL ...)
; file: /home/dunham/8000-benchmarksgame/bench/spectralnorm/spectralnorm.sbcl-8.sbcl
; in: DEFUN EXECUTE-PARALLEL
;     (FUNCALL FUNCTION START END)
; --> SB-C::%FUNCALL THE 
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:%COERCE-CALLABLE-FOR-CALL FUNCTION)
; 
; note: unable to
;   optimize away possible call to FDEFINITION at runtime
; because:
;   FUNCTION is not known to be a function
```

—

```
#+sb-thread
(defun execute-parallel (start end function)
  (declare (type int31 start end))
  (let* ((num-threads 4))
    (loop with step = (truncate (- end start) num-threads)
          for index from start below end by step
          collecting (let ((start index)
                           (end (min end (+ index step))))
                       (sb-thread:make-thread
                        (lambda () (funcall function start end))))
          into threads
          finally (mapcar #'sb-thread:join-thread threads))))

#-sb-thread
(defun execute-parallel (start end function )
  (funcall function start end))
```

(The program is [here](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/spectralnorm-sbcl-8.html). Measurements for similar programs are [here](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/measurements/sbcl.html).)

Is it practical to make SBCL "optimize away possible call to FDEFINITION" or is that compiler note an explanation rather than an opportunity?

Comment: does it matter in your program?

Comment: a few hundredths slower than the other Lisp programs, does it matter enough?

Comment: That's something you need to decide. Also you would need to make sure that FUNCALL gets called with the right data type. Right now in safe code FUNCALL should accept three things: 1) function objects, 2) symbols denoting a function 3) on anything else it will signal an error. If you want to only pass function objects, then you have to ensure that somehow and then 2) and 3) might not be needed.

Comment: You don't seem to wish to provide a specific answer for this specific situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the possible call to `fdefinition` is that it doesn't know that `function` is a function: it might be the name of one: in general it may be a *function designator* rather than a function.  To keep the compiler quiet, explain to it that it is a function with a suitable type declaration, which is `(declare (type function function))`: you just need to declare that its type is `function`).

Rainer is right: there is ε chance that this is ever going to be a performance problem, given you're starting a new thread.  In particular it is fairly likely that adding a declaration will make no difference at all:

- without a declaration the call to `funcall` will get compiled as something like 'check the type of the object: if it is a function, call it; if it is not, call `fdefinition` on it and call the result;';
- with a declaration then the overall function looks like 'check the object is a function, signalling an error if not ... call the function'.

In both cases, if the object is a function, there is one type check and one call: the type check is just in a different place.  In the first case, the code will still work if the object is merely the name of a function, while with the type check it won't.

And in both of these cases this is code where you care calling `make-thread`: if this is *anything like* as fast as a function call, even via `fdefinition` I would be really impressed by the threading system!  Almost certainly the performance of this function is entirely dominated by the overhead of making threads.

Comment: >>a suitable type declaration<< What would that be?

Comment: `(declare (type function ...))`

Comment: You don't seem to wish to provide a specific answer for this specific situation.

Comment: Um: I told you what declaration form to use, what more do you want?

Comment: Thank you, your revised answer is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

**In real code, avoid optimizations like that - unless really needed**

> Is it practical to make SBCL "optimize away possible call to FDEFINITION" or is that compiler note an explanation rather than an opportunity?

Generally it does not matter, especially since most Lisp code **should not** be compiled with optimization qualities `(speed 3) (safety 0) (space 0)`, since it may open up the software to runtime errors and crashes depending on the implementation and program used. Calling things unchecked (without `safety`), other than functions or symbols naming functions, via `funcall` might be dangerous enough to cause a program crash.

For a specific benchmark one might check via timings if a type declaration and a specialized `fdefinition` compilation brings any advantage.

**a type declaration**

A type declaration to make clear that a variable named `fn` is referencing an object of type `function` would be:

```
(declare (type function fn))
```

**in the specific benchmark program FDEFINITION won't be called anyway**

In the example you have provided, `fdefinition` will not be called anyway.

```
(setf foo (lambda (x) x))       ; foo references a function object

(funcall foo 3)
```

`funcall` is probably implemented by something like this:

```
(etypecase f
  ((or cons symbol) (funcall (fdefinition f) ...))
  (function         ...))
```

Since your code passes a function object, there is never the need to call `fdefinition`.

The optimization benefit then will be that the runtime type dispatch can be removed and the dead code for the cons or symbol case...

Comment: As Dan Robertson may have guessed, I compiled with "(speed 3)" because that seemed to force printing of compiler notes I could search for hints. In fact, I was looking for an opportunity to remove the "(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (space 0)))" somone else added to the top of the source file back in 2010.

Comment: About a week ago, on HN, someone mocked that person's Lisp program as doing "some stupidly dangerous things that you should probably never turn on on real software, because they may well make it behave catastrophically badly rather than just crashing when you have a bug." That old program was written for an old SBCL and for a 32 bit OS. Now programs with equivalent performance are shown which do not set safety to 0 and do not print a dozen compiler notes.

Comment: @igouy: one can also just leave the compiler notes as such by just ignoring them or telling the compiler to shut up...

Answer (score 1):

You ask a question about removing an fdefinition but actually your question relies on a premise that the sbcl notes are a good way to drive optimisations and improvements. The notes are a good way to spot obvious issues and places where type declarations can help. They do not tell you what actually makes your program slow. The correct way to improve the performance of a program is to 1. Think if there is a faster algorithm, and 2. Measure it’s performance and work out what is slow.

A single fdefinition call will only matter if it happens in a tight loop (ie it is not single but very plural)

In this case it happens to start a thread. If you are starting threads in a tight loop then your performance problem comes from starting threads in a tight loop. Don’t do that.

If you aren’t starting threads in a tight loop (looking at your code, it appears you are not), there are bigger fish to fry. Why waste time on an `fdefinition` that maybe gets called 4 times per call to `execute-parallel` when you can optimise the inner function instead.

Comment: No, my question does not rely on the premise you state. I don't imagine this is "a good way" — it's the way I have.